# Does string theory remove the singularity of black holes?

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, singularities

One of the reasons we want a theory of
Quantum gravity is to understand black holes and string theory is the most popular approach, but so far I haven't seen any attempt of the theory to remove the black hole singularity the same way loop quantum gravity does.

I don't know much about string theory so I would like to Know if string theory actually does remove the singularity from the Schwarzschild metric  and if yes how does it attempt this?
If no, then how are black holes viewed in string theory, are they singularities in the mathematical sense?

Answer (score 2):

String theory does not avoid black hole singularities, it even generalizes them since in higher dimensions the low-energy supergravity theories have so-called "black brane" solutions which are not point singularities but instead singular on a submanifold of higher dimension (e.g. on a line - the "fundamental string", a surface - the "2-branes", etc.). See for example chapter 18 of *Basic Concepts of String Theory* by Blumenhagen, Lüst, Theisen for a detailed discussion of properties of these solutions.